# Postgres sql round to 2 decimal places

Tags: postgresql, rounding

I am trying to round my division sum results to 2 decimal places in Postgres SQL. I have tried the below, but it rounds them to whole numbers.

```
round((total_sales / total_customers)::numeric,2) as SPC,

round((total_sales / total_orders)::numeric,2) as AOV
```

How can I round the results to 2 decimal places please?

Kind Regards, 
JB78

Answer (score 17):

Assuming total_sales and total_customers are `integer` columns, the expression `total_sales / total_orders` yields an `integer`.

You need to cast at least one of them *before* you can round them, e.g.: `total_sales / total_orders::numeric` to get a decimal result from the division:

```
round(total_sales / total_orders::numeric, 2) as SPC,
round(total_sales / total_orders::numeric, 2) as AOV
```

Example:

```
create table data
(
   total_sales integer,
   total_customers integer, 
   total_orders integer
);

insert into data values (97, 12, 7), (5000, 20, 30);

select total_sales / total_orders as int_result,
       total_sales / total_orders::numeric as numeric_result,
       round(total_sales / total_orders::numeric, 2) as SPC,
       round(total_sales / total_orders::numeric, 2) as AOV
from data;
```

returns:

```
int_result | numeric_result       | spc    | aov   
-----------+----------------------+--------+-------
        13 |  13.8571428571428571 |  13.86 |  13.86
       166 | 166.6666666666666667 | 166.67 | 166.67
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have tried casting and it still hasn't worked. Where does the cast bit need to go please?

Comment: @JB78: as I have shown: cast one of the _columns_ to numeric, not the result.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name. I have tried                                       
              total_sales / total_customers::numeric as numeric_result
  total_sales / total_orders::numeric as numeric_result,
  round((total_sales / total_customers)::numeric,2) as SPC,
  round((total_sales / total_orders)::numeric,2) as AOV      but it is still producing whole numbers for SPC and AOV. Is it because total_customers is a whole number to begin with please?

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(*column_name*, 2) from table_name;
```

will give us round to 2 decimal values in postgres